# fetch list from firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I am trying to fetch an array from firebase but I have this error

Class 'Configurations' has no instance method '[]'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Configurations'
Tried calling:

here is my model class
`

```
class Configurations {
  final List<dynamic> brands;

  Configurations({
    required this.brands,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'brands': brands,
      };

  static Configurations fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Configurations(
        brands: json['brands'],
      );
}
```

`

```
  Stream<List<dynamic>> readConfi() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Configurations')
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
            .map((doc) => Configurations.fromJson(doc.data()))
            .toList());
  }



Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
            stream: readConfi(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              print(snapshot.error);
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final brands = snapshot.data!;
                return ListView(
                  children: brands.map<Widget>((brands) {
                    return new ListTile(
                      title: new Text(brands['brands']),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                );
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
            },
          )),
```

`

here is and image for data I want to fetch
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you've actually got a `List<Configurations>` from the `readConfi()`'s stream, so change it to this.

```
  Stream<List<Configurations>> readConfi() {
return FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Configurations')
    .snapshots()
    .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
        .map((doc) => Configurations.fromJson(doc.data()))
        .toList());
  }
```

now you can access properties on the `Configurations` objects like you will do with an other class, so you need to change your `StreamBuilder` to this:

```
Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder<List<Configurations>>(
            stream: readConfi(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Configurations>>snapshot) {
              print(snapshot.error);
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final brands = snapshot.data!; // this is a List<Configurations>
                return ListView(
                  children: brands.map<Widget>((brands) {
                    return new ListTile(
                      title: new Text(brands.brands),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                );
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
            }

   ,
           )),
```

Comment: hello, thank you for answer it works, but how I can user it inside listview.builder